# Remove certain strings from list of strings as column in pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
    index    question_id    tag
    0        1858           [pset3, game-of-fifteen]
    1        2409           [pset4]
    2        4346           [pset6, cs50submit]
    3        9139           [pset8, pset5, gradebook]
    4        9631           [pset4, recover]
```

I need to remove every string from list of strings in `tag` column except `pset*` strings.

So I need to end with something like this:

```
    index    question_id    tag
    0        1858           [pset3]
    1        2409           [pset4]
    2        4346           [pset6]
    3        9139           [pset8, pset5]
    4        9631           [pset4]
```

How can I do that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option: Use `apply` method to loop through the items in the `tag` column; for each item, use a list comprehension to filter strings based on the prefix using `startswith` method:

```
df['tag'] = df.tag.apply(lambda lst: [x for x in lst if x.startswith("pset")])
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a function to the `tag` series that constructs a list using only the elements that start with `'pset'`

```
df.tag.apply(lambda x: [xx for xx in x if xx.startswith('pset')])

# returns:
0           [pset3]
1           [pset4]
2           [pset6]
3    [pset8, pset5]
4           [pset4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can even use python in operator

```
df.tag = df.tag.apply(lambda x: [elem for elem in x if 'pset' in elem])

0           [pset3]
1           [pset4]
2           [pset6]
3    [pset8, pset5]
4           [pset4]
```